# Why does XMM's performance differ significantly from its benchmark index?

Tags: canada, etf

[XMM](https://www.blackrock.com/ca/individual/en/products/239640/ishares-msci-emerging-markets-minimum-volatility-index-etf) is a Canadian-listed iShares ETF that tracks the [MSCI Emerging Markets Minimum Volatility Index](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/2acc78ef-daba-4c10-bd81-c685f129b1f5). Its holdings are 99% [EEMV](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239641/ishares-msci-emerging-markets-minimum-volatility-etf), the US-listed version of the same ETF.

While EEMV tracks its index fairly well, XMM is completely different, which is very strange since all it holds is EEMV.

Sample calendar performance:

```
+------+------------+-------+-------------+
| Year | MSCI Index |  XMM  | "Benchmark" |
+------+------------+-------+-------------+
| 2015 | -11.67     | 4.93  | 5.48        |
| 2016 | 4.36       | -0.86 | 0.31        |
| 2017 | 27.21      | 18.27 | 18.40       |
| 2018 | -5.38      | 2.14  | 2.71        |
+------+------------+-------+-------------+
```

While the tooltip for that "benchmark" does show
[image]

the numbers look nothing like that actual index (linked above), nor its underlying ETF EEMV. How can this be explained?

Comment: Are they both listed in the same currency?

Comment: XMM is listed in CAD and EEMV is listed in US. Could that explain such a wide difference in returns?

Comment: I'm seeing that over the course of the year 2016, the Canadian dollar became 3.49% stronger, relative to the US dollar. So my question is how XMM did so much *better* than the benchmark in 2016: instead of merely gaining 0.31% of its value in USD, it managed the greater feat of losing only 0.86% of its value in CAD.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I made the mistake of comparing it to the USD version of the index; the [CAD version](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/7e81d051-c794-495c-9d18-e5d52e1562a4) (for gross returns, not [net returns](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/28b8f76c-d12d-4459-8dc9-4968c8b993e9)) lists the exact same numbers as XMM's benchmark.

I didn't run the numbers, but the differences are presumably attributable to fluctuations in currency and management fees.